# jQuery event ordering

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that requires the user to click twice to execute the normal click handler. The plugin is here: https://github.com/aduyng/bootstrap-confirm-button.

What I did was that when bootstrapConfirmButton() is called on a button, I remove all click event handlers, attach my event handler, and finally call all original click event handlers when on the second click. the So far it works fine and does the job. However, if you register another click event handler after bootstrapConfirmButton(), it is still invoked on the first click.

How do I fix this issue or if you have a solution, can you please fork the repository and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `stopPropagation`, I used `stopImmediatePropagation`, and I moved the call inside the nearby conditional to allow propagation the second time the button is clicked.  Is that the behavior you're after?

```
$this.bind('click', function (event) {
    // Old stuff:
    //event.preventDefault();
    //event.stopPropagation();

    var settings = $(event.currentTarget).data('settings');
    if (!$this.hasClass(settings.class)) {
        set($this);

        // New stuff:
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        return;
    }
    settings.sure(event, $this);
});
```

Comment: You're right. I confused about event handler order. Your solution shoud be valid.